# How do I invert an affine transformation with translation, rotation, and scaling?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I have a 4x4 matrix with translation, rotation, and scaling components, but no shear or other transformations. How do I find its inverse? I'm using the Eigen library in c++.

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky to get right, since the operations need to be performed in the correct order:

```
template<class Derived>
Matrix4f AffineInverse(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& mat)
{
    Matrix3f RotSclInv = (
        mat.block<3, 3>(0, 0).array().rowwise()
        / mat.block<3, 3>(0, 0).colwise().squaredNorm().array() //scaling
        ).transpose(); //rotation
    return (Matrix4f(4,4) << RotSclInv
        , -RotSclInv * mat.block<3, 1>(0, 3) //translation
        , 0, 0, 0, 1).finished();
}
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2625420/603688) states, the inverse of the top left 3x3 block can be calculated separately:

```
inv ([ A b ]) = [inv(A)  -inv(A)*b]
    ([ 0 1 ])   [  0          1   ]
```

The key insight for the top left block is that the scaling and rotation is equal to a orthogonal (rotation) matrix `Q` times a diagonal (scaling) matrix `D`: `Q*D`. To invert it, do some linear algebra:

```
  inv(Q*D)
= transp(transp(inv(Q*D)))
= transp(inv(transp(Q*D)))
= transp(inv(transp(D)*transp(Q)))
```

(see [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose)), and since `D` is diagonal and `Q` is orthogonal,

```
= transp(inv(D*inv(Q)))
= transp(Q*inv(D))).
```

`Q*inv(D)` is easy to find: Since in `Q*D` each column is a column of `Q` (which is a unit vector) times an entry of `D` (which is a scalar), it is enough to divide each column by the square of its norm. This is what the first three lines of the function do.

Written out fully in linear algebra form:

```
inv ([ Q*D b ]) = [transp(Q*inv(D))  -transp(Q*inv(D))*b]
    ([ 0   1 ])   [       0                 1           ]
```

Comment: can you explain how do you get from transp(transp(inv(Q*D))) to transp(inv(transp(Q*D))) ? i understand transp(X) = inv(X) if X is orthonormal matrix which only applies for the rotation matrix but not for scale rotation matrix.

Comment: @bysreg That identity is actually true for any invertible matrix. See [the proof here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340233/transpose-of-inverse-vs-inverse-of-transpose)

Comment: thanks. the link proves transp(inv(M)) = inv(transp(M)). but, just to be clear,  the transp(X) = inv(X) only works for orthogonal (not only orthonormal, which i mentioned in the previous comment). but yea, that proof answer my question

Comment: What is the reason this cannot be represented as an Eigen Transform which has an `inverse()` method?