Is there a better way to write SIMD code to invert a transformation matrix?
I am writing a maths library for a raytracer project, and so I'm trying to make my heavy operations (like matrix inverse) more optimised.
After doing some research, I discovered this trick to invert a transformation matrix (described in more detail in this document I made) where I store my transformation matrix as three different matrices (scaling, rotation, and translation). Then I just invert each one of them, and combine the matrices to get the final result, the inverse.
Code:
#include <immintrin.h>

typedef union u_vec4s
{
    float       a[4];
    __m128      simd;
    struct
    {
        float   x;
        float   y;
        float   z;
        float   w;
    };
}__attribute((aligned(16))) t_vec4s;

typedef union u_mat4s
{
    float       a[4][4];
    __m128      simd[4];
    __m256      _ymm[2];
    struct
    {
        t_vec4s   r1;
        t_vec4s   r2;
        t_vec4s   r3;
        t_vec4s   r4;
    };
}__attribute((aligned(16))) t_mat4s;

t_mat4s lag_get_transform_matrix_inverse(const t_mat4s s, const t_mat4s r, const t_mat4s t)
{
    // const __m128 zeros = _mm_set1_ps(0);
    const __m128 mul00 = _mm_set_ps(1, -t.r3.w, -t.r2.w, -t.r1.w);
    t_mat4s t1w0;
    t_mat4s s1rr;

    __m128 tmp0 = _mm_unpacklo_ps(r.simd[0], r.simd[1]); // [r00, r10, r01, r11]
    __m128 tmp1 = _mm_unpackhi_ps(r.simd[0], r.simd[1]); // [r02, r12, r03, r13]
    __m128 tmp2 = _mm_unpacklo_ps(r.simd[2], r.simd[3]); // [r20, r30, r21, r31]
    __m128 tmp3 = _mm_unpackhi_ps(r.simd[2], r.simd[3]); // [r22, r32, r23, r33]

    s1rr.simd[0] = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_movelh_ps(tmp0, tmp2), _mm_set1_ps(1.f / s.r1.x)); // [r00/sx, r10/sx, r20/sx, r30/sx]
    s1rr.simd[1] = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_movehl_ps(tmp2, tmp0), _mm_set1_ps(1.f / s.r2.y)); // [r01/sy, r11/sy, r21/sy, r31/sy]
    s1rr.simd[2] = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_movelh_ps(tmp1, tmp3), _mm_set1_ps(1.f / s.r3.z)); // [r02/sz, r12/sz, r22/sz, r32/sz]
    s1rr.simd[3] = _mm_movehl_ps(tmp3, tmp1); // [0, 0, 0, 1]

    t1w0.simd[0] = /*_mm_sub_ps(zeros, */_mm_dp_ps(s1rr.simd[0], mul00, 0xF1)/*)*/;
    t1w0.simd[1] = /*_mm_sub_ps(zeros, */_mm_dp_ps(s1rr.simd[1], mul00, 0xF1)/*)*/;
    t1w0.simd[2] = /*_mm_sub_ps(zeros, */_mm_dp_ps(s1rr.simd[2], mul00, 0xF1)/*)*/;

    s1rr.r1.w = _mm_cvtss_f32(t1w0.simd[0]);
    s1rr.r2.w = _mm_cvtss_f32(t1w0.simd[1]);
    s1rr.r3.w = _mm_cvtss_f32(t1w0.simd[2]);

    return (s1rr);
}

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a more efficient method to achieve the same result? Or maybe I'm doing some unneeded operations. I know that one thing I could do to make it faster is to store my rotation matrix in column-order as opposed to row-order, that way, it wouldn't have to be transposed.
One other thing, possibly, is to avoid using _mm_dp_ps, as that function is kinda heavy, and it's possibly better to just use a horizontal add instead. Something like:
t1w0.simd[0] = _mm_mul_ps(s1rr.simd[0], mul00);
_mm_storeu_ps((float *)&t1w0.r1, _mm_hadd_ps(t1w0.simd[0], t1w0.simd[0]));
s1rr.r1.w = t1w0.r1.a[0] + t1w0.r1.a[2];

Is that a worthwhile thing to do? Are there any thoughts or suggestions?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624422/efficient-4x4-matrix-inverse-affine-transform

Hello, @beaker. Thank you kindly for taking the time to reply! I believe the case they're talking about is for a general transformation matrix (already composed and you don't know the transformations that made it up). I'm talking a more specific case (you know the separate components of the transformation matrix).

Re "Are there any thoughts or suggestions?" The generality of this question suggests it may be a better fit at Code Review Stackexchange. For this site you would want to have one specific programming question that lends itself to a specific answer. I am guessing that this resulted in the one close vote I see right now.

You have the transformation decomposed as scale, rotation and translation, but want the inverse only in it's composed form? What do you want to do with the (inverted) transformation? Apply it to vectors, concatenate with other transformations, possibly invert it again?

The reason why I did this, @chtz, is because it's much easier to calculate the transform when the matrix is decomposed as opposed to when those components are baked in

Your 3 input matrices are using 192 bytes of memory or 12 SSE vectors. However, they only keep 15 floats = 60 bytes of data, the rest of the elements are zeros. This is very inefficient way to store decomposed transformation and pass it to functions.
If you’re certain you know what you’re doing i.e. you need to invert a huge pile of different matrices, the profiler shows the inversion is the bottleneck, you have tested your stuff with XMMatrixInverse from DirectXMath (the linked repo uses copy-paste friendly MIT license) and unhappy with the performance, refactor your function to take scale and translation in a single vector as opposed to 4x4 matrices.
Then do something like that. The following code is in C++, requires AVX1 (easy to downgrade if needed, replace _mm_permute_ps( v ) with _mm_shuffle_ps( v, v )) and it’s untested.
#include <immintrin.h>

// A row major 3x3 or 4x3 matrix stored in 3 SSE vectors
struct Mat3
{
    __m128 rows[ 3 ];
};

inline __m128 broadcastX( __m128 v ) { return _mm_permute_ps( v, _MM_SHUFFLE( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) ); }
inline __m128 broadcastY( __m128 v ) { return _mm_permute_ps( v, _MM_SHUFFLE( 1, 1, 1, 1 ) ); }
inline __m128 broadcastZ( __m128 v ) { return _mm_permute_ps( v, _MM_SHUFFLE( 2, 2, 2, 2 ) ); }

Mat3 invertDecomposed( Mat3 rot, __m128 scale, __m128 translation )
{
    // Invert the scale vector
    __m128 scaleInv = _mm_div_ps( _mm_set1_ps( 1 ), scale );
    // Negate the translation vector
    translation = _mm_sub_ps( _mm_setzero_ps(), translation );

    // Multiply rows of the rotation matrix by components of the inverted scale
    __m128 r0 = _mm_mul_ps( rot.rows[ 0 ], broadcastX( scaleInv ) );
    __m128 r1 = _mm_mul_ps( rot.rows[ 1 ], broadcastY( scaleInv ) );
    __m128 r2 = _mm_mul_ps( rot.rows[ 2 ], broadcastZ( scaleInv ) );

    // Compute last column of the output matrix
    // Note VDPPS can place output number into any lanes, we need it in W
    __m128 r03 = _mm_dp_ps( r0, translation, 0b01111000 );
    __m128 r13 = _mm_dp_ps( r1, translation, 0b01111000 );
    __m128 r23 = _mm_dp_ps( r2, translation, 0b01111000 );

    // Insert numbers into the last column
    r0 = _mm_blend_ps( r0, r03, 0b1000 );
    r1 = _mm_blend_ps( r1, r13, 0b1000 );
    r2 = _mm_blend_ps( r2, r23, 0b1000 );

    // Return the result
    Mat3 result;
    result.rows[ 0 ] = r0;
    result.rows[ 1 ] = r1;
    result.rows[ 2 ] = r2;
    return result;
}


I think you could arrange for _mm_or_ps instead of _mm_blend_ps which saves a byte of code size per instruction and makes it only SSE2 not SSE4.1 in case that matters.  Shouldn't really matter for performance; immediate blends are fast on most CPUs..  We can make the W element of scaleinv 0 with div(  setr(1, 1, 1, Infinity), scale) for finite scale, and adjust the shuffles to keep the top element where it is.  So the vector constant is no longer simple, can't be a vbroadcastss load, so might cost extra bytes in .rodata if compilers had been optimizing well.

Unless r03 and so on need that top element set in r0-r2, in which case yeah you need a blendps or insertps, with blendps being faster.

I did not test this, but I assume at some point the rot matrix needs to get transposed.

@chtz When writing that code I was looking at the OP’s google document with the math. Transposing the input rotation matrix gonna save relatively expensive _mm_dp_ps instructions, however assuming OP wants row-major output, need to transpose back at the end of the function.

Yes, but if the input rot is row-major and the (inverted) output is supposed to be row-major, you need to transpose it -- unless it is assumed that the rotation was already inverted ...
